# Amazon Lambda - Alias specific configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have setup a Amazon Lambda function that has different Aliases for development, test and production and an API gateway that has several stages pointing to the respective Alias versions.

Now I want to access a database table and obviously each Alias should access it's own table. In the documentation I couldn't find a possibility to pass an Alias specific configuration to my function. Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

Setup [Stage Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html) in API Gateway, and add something like the following to your mapping template(s) to pass those stage variables to the Lambda functions.

```
  "stage-variables" : {
    #foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
      "$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
```

The Lambda functions can then pull things like DB table names from the event object.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution for functions that are exposed via API gateway. Is there a similar best practice for functions which are triggered by S3 or SNS?

Comment: Unfortunately those are more difficult. You could possibly use a DynamoDB table to store settings specific to different function aliases. Then you could check the `context` object to get the `functionVersion` value and then lookup the settings from DynamoDB.

Comment: It looks like you can also get the alias from `process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION`

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Instead of using a DynamoDB table I use a config file, but otherwise I use your suggestion